# How can I reference a class variable as an item in a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a strategy game and I want to create a listbox. The listbox should show the items aka. civilizations to choose from. I already created classes:

```
public class Civilization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public CivAbility UniqueAb1{get;set;}
    public CivAbility UniqueAb2 { get; set; }
    public Unit UniqueUnit1 { get; set; } 
    public Unit UniqueUnit2 { get; set; }
    public Building UniqueBuild1 { get; set; }
    public Building UniqueBuild2 { get; set; }
    public Improvement UniqueImprove1 { get; set; }

    public Civilization(int id, string name, string ownername, CivAbility uniqueab1, 
                         Unit uniqueunit1 = null, Unit uniqueunit2 = null, 
                         Building uniquebuild1 = null, Building uniquebuild2 = null, 
                         Improvement uniqueImprove1=null)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        UniqueUnit1 = uniqueunit1;

    }
}
```

Here is the part in my World class where I define types of these classes. I also created constants to use as Id like CIV_ID_GERMAN for "Germany". The rest of the variables ar the display name, the name for units owned by Germany and the name of their ability:

```
Civilization Germany = new Civilization(CIV_ID_GERMAN,"Germany","German", FurorTeutonicus);
```

And here is part of the main program that should add "Germany" in the listbox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Player _player;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxCiv.Items.Add(new Civilization(CIV_ID_GERMAN, "Germany", 
            "German", FurorTeutonicus));
    }
}
```

It shows error for CIV_ID_GERMAN and FurorTeutonicus "does not exist in the current context".

How to make it work?

Comment: Well what is `FurorTeutonicus`? Did you perhaps mean `CivAbility.FurorTeutonicus`?

Comment: When you ask a question about the identifier `FurorTeutonicus`, *tell us what it is*. Give us all the information you have about `FurorTeutonicus`. You left in enough of a hint for DavidG to figure it out, but in the future, don't assume we've seen the rest of your code. Also: Did you remove part of the body of that constructor for brevity, or are you really only initializing three out of ten properties in your actual code?